# how to call the function in the vimrc depend on the filetype

Tags: vim

I have a function in the vimrc. The function is about completing the tag in the html.

```
 42 function! InsertHtmlTag()
 43     let pat = '\c<\w\+\s*\(\s\+\w\+\s*=\s*[''#$;,()."a-z0-9]\+\)*\s*>'
 44     normal! a>
 45     let save_cursor = getpos('.')
 46     let result = matchstr(getline(save_cursor[1]), pat)
 47     if (search(pat, 'b', save_cursor[1]))
 48         normal! lyiwf>
 49         normal! a</
 50         normal! p
 51         normal! a>
 52     endif
 53     :call cursor(save_cursor[1], save_cursor[2], save_cursor[3])
 54 endfunction
 55 inoremap > <ESC>:call InsertHtmlTag()<CR>
```

But I found some trouble recently. When I write C++ code, after I write `#include <iostream>`, the vim complete it with `</iostream>`....
I wonder a way to call this function only if the filetype is .html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim allows for filetype-specific configuration. Move the snippet from your `~/.vimrc` to e.g. `~/.vim/ftplugin/html_inserttag.vim`, and make the mapping buffer-local:

```
inoremap <buffer> > <ESC>:call InsertHtmlTag()<CR>
```

This requires that you have `:filetype plugin on` in your `~/.vimrc`. See `:help filetypes` for more information.